# Filter array over multiple properties with filter and every

Tags: javascript

I want to filter array of objects over multiple properties but I am getting always the entire data. I just want to get the filtered data, e.g ['data_x']. What is wrong with my code?

```
export const testData= [

      {
        "data_z": {
          "points": [
            {
              "name": "Juli",
              "geb": "27.12.1982",
              "lastname": 'Peter'
            }
          ]
        },
        "data_x": {
          "points": [
            {
              "name": "Dennis",
              "geb": "27.12.1981",
              "lastname": 'Peter'
            }
          ]
        },
        "data_p": {
          "points": [
            {
              "name": "Janni",
              "geb": "27.12.1980",
              "lastname": 'Peter'
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]


let filterData = ['data_x', 'data_y'];

let testData = this.filterChartData(filterData);
console.log(testData);// ---> here I am getting the entire data

filterChartData(filterKeys){
    return this.testData.filter((item) => {
        return filterKeys.every(key => item[key]);
 });
  }
```

Comment: `TESTDATEN` seems does not work. Seems missing or extra `{}`

Comment: what is `this.chartData` and expected output?

Comment: Can there be multiple objects on the array?

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to get the filtered data, e.g ['data_x']

Use `filter` and `map`

```
var allKeys = testData.map( s => Object.keys(s) )[0];

console.log(filterData.filter( s => allKeys.includes(s) ).map( s => testData[0][s] ));
```

**Demo**

```js
var testData = [
  {
    "data_z": {
      "points": [{
        "name": "Juli",
        "geb": "27.12.1982",
        "lastname": 'Peter'
      }]
    },
    "data_x": {
      "points": [{
        "name": "Dennis",
        "geb": "27.12.1981",
        "lastname": 'Peter'
      }]
    },
    "data_p": {
      "points": [{
        "name": "Janni",
        "geb": "27.12.1980",
        "lastname": 'Peter'
      }]
    }
  }
];

let filterData = ['data_x', 'data_y'];

var allKeys = testData.map( s => Object.keys(s) )[0];

console.log(filterData.filter( s => allKeys.includes(s) ).map( s => testData[0][s] ));
```

Comment: Whats about if I want filter multiple values ['data_x', 'data_z']

Comment: @NoahTony Please check again, it will filter for multiple values.

Comment: @NoahTony I have attached a demo.

Comment: Don't understand how you can apply it to my example above

Comment: @NoahTony did you checked the demo?

Comment: Yes it is good. But the question was what is wrong with my code :-)

Comment: @NoahTony I broke down the problems with your code in my answer.  Let me know if you have any questions about my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

from the filter function return a Boolean in your case the condition would comparing the keys

The newly generated array will have element that had return value true from filter function

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't loop all your objects array, it just create an array of 2 strings 'data_x' & 'data_y', the the call of your method loops between these strings and the result of the method, (and this isn't well factored to TS syntax)
this may help:

```
let filteredTestData = testData.map(test => [test.data_p, test.data_x])

console.log(filteredTestData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Noah, I gather from your comments that you mainly want to understand why your code isn't producing the desired result rather than receiving a working solution.  Here you go:

**Problem #1:**

The 'filter' method isn't filtering what you think it is filtering.  The 'filter' method is being called on the 'testData' array, which only has one object element in it.  The objects you are trying to filter are nested within that single object.  So, calling 'filter' on 'testData' can only ever return either:

- An array with a single object in it, just like 'testData'  OR
- An empty array

**Problem #2:**

I don't think the 'every' method is doing quite what you think it is doing.  As written, the condition you are providing to 'every' is testing to make sure that all of the filter keys are present as property keys on the object and have truthy values.  So, in your code 'every' will do the following:

- return true if all keys are properties on 'item' and each property
  references a truthy value
- return false if some keys are not present as properties on 'item'
- return false if some of the referenced values are falsy

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

**I have demonstrated this with some code below:**

```js
// simplifying testData to make it easier to read and understand

let testData = [ // this is the array that testData references

  { // this is the 'parent' object that constitutes the single element of testData

    // these are nested objects within that single object element
    'data_z': { 'points': 'this is data_z' },
    'data_x': { 'points': 'this is data_x' },
    'data_p': { 'points': 'this is data_p' },

  }

];

function filterChartData(filterKeys) {
  return testData.filter((item) => {
    return filterKeys.every(key => item[key]);
  });
}

// returns an array like the original testData, because the single object in testData matches the test condition put forward by 'every':
// Why? 'data_x' and 'data_z' are present as property keys on the object, and both reference truthy values
console.log('Result #1: ', filterChartData(['data_x', 'data_z']));

// returns an empty array, because the single object in testData does NOT match the test condition put forward by 'every':
// Why? 'data_y' is not present as a property key on the object
console.log('Result #2: ', filterChartData(['data_x', 'data_y']));


// assigning a different value to testData to show a different condition

testData = [

  {

    'data_z': { 'points': 'this is data_z' },
    'data_x': { 'points': 'this is data_x' },
    'data_p': undefined,

  }

];

// returns an empty array, because the single object in testData does NOT match the test condition put forward by 'every':
// Why? 'data_p' is present as a property key but is undefined and therefore falsy
console.log('Result #3: ', filterChartData(['data_x', 'data_p']));
```